# Xcode - New View

Tags: ios, xcode, view, storyboard, viewcontroller

I am extremely new to Xcode and Apple Swift and I am making a SpriteKit game.

I want to make a main menu and I know how to add a new view controller in the storyboard, but I'm not sure what code files to link it up to or if I need to make some in my project. My Game View Controller has some files attached and I would like the same for my main menu.

Thanks in advance,

Will

Comment: Yes. I want a variable to be changed when I press a button in the main menu.

Comment: @trojanfoe I am really unsure.